# trying to get a .settings file in my program

Tags: c#, .net, github

I'm trying to get a .settings file for my program but it doesn't seem to appear in my folder/ program. when i expand the properties in the solution explorer there is nothing in there at all.
I am using the program through a Repo on GitHub and so this could be the reason

Is there anyway to create a new .settings file or simply locate the file.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some kind of proof that there was ever a .settings file for the project? What kind of project is it?

Comment: Reading over this might help. Seems like there may be a custom settings file in your project, or one simply doesn't exist. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019#create-application-settings-at-design-time

Comment: @itsme86 im actually not sure if there was one or not  but its just a regular console application

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your problem is with Visual Studio and not exactly with .Net, right?

Maybe the problem is that the .settings is not added properly to the project, so you can right click on the "Solutions Explorer" and go to "Add -> Existing Item" and manually add the file to the project.